# Programmatically start / launch VPN connection

Tags: android

I am developing Enterprise applications that need to connect to
servers behind the firewall.  Can my app start VPN connection
programmatically?

On 2.0+ platforms, VPN is supported by the platform.  Assuming user
has already setup VPN parameters, can my app start the VPN
connection?  Suppose user has not setup any VPN parameters, can my app
supply those parameters? and start VPN connection?

Answer (score 1):

We're facing this problem at our shop. For now our best shot is trying to use Android internal API to connect to the VPN the same way that the system preferences app does.

First, you need to set up an environment that allows you to access internal API: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Then we can implement something like this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.4_r1/com/android/settings/vpn2/VpnSettings.java#258

I don't know if we will have any permission issues with this, but IMHO this is the best option we have right now

EDIT: this need root privileges in order to avoid `java.lang.SecurityException: Unauthorized Caller` errors.

Comment: did you successfully implement this solution and worked with you, please reply as I am facing the same problem, and want to be able to configure VPN connection from code, or even turn on/off vpn connection from code

Comment: nope @AmiraElsayedIsmail, we gave up with the `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose user has not setup any VPN parameters, can my app supply those parameters? and start VPN connection?

yes, I think it's possible with `VpnService` class as in [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java)

> Assuming user has already setup VPN parameters, can my app start the VPN connection?

I'm looking for it also. I'm not sure, but I think maybe it can be done with `android.net.vpn`. See [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/net/vpn/PptpProfile.java)

Answer (score 0):

AnyConnect by Cisco has private API: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin30/acmobiledevices.html#71308

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can start a VPN connection.what version of android are you using? [this link should be useful](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6-highlights.html) . give details for better understanding.

Comment: That link only mentions that VPN is available, and references the settings menu.